# Equation has real solution; why doesn't NSolve find it?

Tags: equation-solving

For real value x in (-3,3)
there's a real solution of a derivative equation `f[x]=2^x-x` (`f'[x]=2^x*ln2-1)

```
f[x_]:=2^x-x
sol = NSolve[f'[x],x]
```

But the answer is 1. (0.528766  + (0.  + 9.06472 I) c1∈**Z**
why my computer answer like this, although there's a real solution around 0.6xxx

[image]

PS: Anybody is on a same boat?

Comment: `f[x_] := 2^x - x; sol = NSolve[{f'[x], -3 < x < 3}, x]` or `f[x_] := 2^x - x; sol = NSolve[{f'[x] == 0, -3 < x < 3}, x]` or `sol = NSolve[f'[x], x, Reals]`

Comment: In your result setting `C[1]` to zero gives the result you are looking for. `sol/.C[1]->0`

Comment: Thank you @BobHanlon.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your equation has an infinite number of complex solutions. `NSolve` found a  general expression for **all** of them dependent on integer `C[1]`. The real one has `C[1]` of 0:

```
sol /. C[1] -> 0
(* {{x -> 0.528766 + 0. I}}
```

Or you can just do:

```
sol = NSolve[f'[x], x, Reals]
(* {{x -> 0.528766}} *)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot!!!